# Radio button in angular js select only first radio button no other radio button is selected

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Here is my controller

```
app.controller('testController',function($scope){

    $scope.categorys = [
                {name:'Paintings',value:'1'},
                {name:'Photography',value:'2'},
                {name:'Drawings',value:'3'},
                {name:'Sculpture',value:'4'}
            ];
})
```

In my html

```
<div class="grid-two" ng-repeat="category in categorys">
                                <div class="image-thumb">
                                    <p>{{category.name}}</p>
                                    <figure>
                                        <img src="/images/1.jpg">
                                    </figure>
                                    <input ng-model="art.category" ng-value="category.value" type="radio"  id="seling3"/>
                                    <label for="seling3" class="blue-overlay">
                                        <i class="icon icon-tick c-sprite"></i>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

It prints the radio button properly however i can only select  first radio button no other radio button is selected
Whats the problem i've tried so many question but none of them are not similar to my issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to give different IDs for each `input[type="radio"]`:

```
<input ng-model="art.category" ng-value="category.value" type="radio" 
 id="seling{{category.value}}"/>
<label for="seling{{category.value}}" class="blue-overlay">
    <i class="icon icon-tick c-sprite"></i>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the `art.category` object in the controller like this

```
app.controller('testController',function($scope){
      $scope.art = {'category' : ''} 
})
```

Demo

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){
  $scope.art = {'category' : ''}
  $scope.categorys = [
      {name:'Paintings',value:'1'},
      {name:'Photography',value:'2'},
      {name:'Drawings',value:'3'},
      {name:'Sculpture',value:'4'}
  ];
})
```

```css
<figure>
                                        <img src="/images/1.jpg">
                                    </figure>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
<div class="grid-two" ng-repeat="category in categorys">
                                <div class="image-thumb">
                                    <p>{{category.name}}</p>
                                    <figure>
                                        <img src="/images/1.jpg">
                                    </figure>
                                    <input ng-model="art.category" ng-value="category.value" type="radio"  id="seling3"/>
                                    <label for="seling3" class="blue-overlay">
                                        <i class="icon icon-tick c-sprite"></i>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
</div>
```